# VB.NET Check if computer has a Wi-Fi adapter

Tags: vb.net, wifi

I'm making an application that analyzes exhaustively the PC, I want to detect the presence or lack of wifi on laptop

Answer (score 1):

i think this may solve your question

```
imports System.net
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation
Dim adapters() As NetworkInterface = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces() 
    For Each adapter As NetworkInterface In adapters 
        If adapter.NetworkInterfaceType = NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211 Then 
           MessageBox.Show("wireless found")
        End If 

   next
```

Comment: **This does not compile**. Please check and update your answer.

Comment: Thanks... In order to get the device name, use `adapter.description`